# How to get an external link to update google sheets automatically?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets

I have been searching the internet for a while now and i can't really seem to find any answers for my query what i am looking for is this...

**Runescape Grand Exchange Market**

For example:~

**Runite Bar** Is "**14,378 coins**"

But it changes from time to time depending on the "**game economy**"

How can i use this number to auto update in google spreadsheet?

For example 1 bar is **14,378 coins**. If i choose to put **2** Bars I would like the price of the item to be changed also so it's **28,756 coins**.

What i have done at the moment is to make this **Runite Bar** you require certain items such as:

**1. Runite Ore x1**

**2. Coal x8**

I have set the value to auto update when i choose to purchase 100 **Runite Ores** It will automatically update how much **Coal** i need which would be "**800**" but what i want is to auto update the "**PRICE**" of the **BAR**

So if I choose to purchase:~

- 300 Runite Ore (1) - 10,975 - i would like this also to be updated automatically.
- 2400 Coal (x8)- 2,504 - i would like this also to be updated automatically.

Cost would be: 4,043,700 Coins - This is the total and should be updated automatically.

But if somebody tells me how to get price of an external site i can maybe do the Runite Ore & Coal myself i hope..lol

Runite Bar Website = [Runescape Wikipedia - Rune Bar](http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Rune_bar) - as you can see it says "**Exchange price**" THAT is what i want in spreadsheet to be updated automatically.

- Best Regards

Antartika

Comment: yeah sort of and updates every 2 hours yeah im fine with that because i think the website updates every 12h or so how do i do that anywho? xD

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=substitute(left(index(importxml("http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Rune_bar","//td"),15,1),6),",","")*1
```

the `//td` part should import the entire table (the one in the middle of the page). It is XPath code that seems to me not at all well documented but [ZVON](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/) might help.

*index* `15,1` then takes the fifteenth row and the first column (ie `14,573 coins`) of that table. These are the parameters to change to select other cells from that table.

*left* strips off the `coins` part, but since a function that manipulates text results in a string, so the comma is a 'character' rather than formatting feature. However

*substitute* replaces the `,` with `""`(ie with nothing) so that when we multiply by one (*1) we get a number that we can then multiply again by however many bars are involved.

Comment: wow that worked but how do i do that for another item for example if i wanted to? could you teach me or would it be hard? or do i just change the URL link?, is there some sort of video for this tutorial? ;o